# How should I use the IF statement in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables: Persons and Statuses and have created two classes **Person** and **Status**. I am using following code to show the error message "*Only one status is allowed*". The code is not working - I think there is some problem in my If statement.

```
          <ul>
              <% Person.all.each do |person| %>
                <li>
                  <%= person.name %>
                  <% if status.size >= 1 %>
                     <em>Only one status is allowed</em>
                  <% end %>

                </li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
```

**Table Persons**

```
U_Id    Name    Place
  1    James    Florida
  2    Mark     California
  3    Steve    Newyork
```

**Table Statuses**

```
Id    Status    U_Id
 1    Hi          1
 2    OMG         2
 3    Bye         3
 4    Help me     2
```

**Problem:** Mark has posted 2 status his `U_Id is 2`, I want to show him a error message like **Only one post is allowed**. How this can be done?

Update:

Person class

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Comment: Where does the `tweet` in line 5 come from?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel My mistake.... It is status

Comment: Show us your Person class declaration. Probably you need to write `person.status.size` instead of just `status.size`

Comment: Yes, I can show you my both classes,please wait

Comment: Doean't matter. It stil comes out of thin air.

Comment: How does this Person class affects the If statement

Answer (score 3):

Your programming logic is incorrect. You are trying to impose a limit on the number of status messages a user can have, but it seems you are enforcing that limit too late, because you are printing an error message when the status is displayed rather than when it is submitted. The people viewing these messages are presumably other users and they hardly care if Mark violates your design constraints.

You have two options.

#### Limit the number of statuses one a user can have to one.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
end
```

This will allow you to do:

```
steve = User.find(3)
steve.status
=> "Bye"
```

#### Only display the last one

Alternatively, you can allow unlimited statuses, but only display the latest one.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
end

mark = User.find(2)
mark.statuses.last
=> "Help me"
```

On a side note... if users truly only have one status and the former statuses do not matter, then you should consider removing the status model and including the status as a string attribute on the user model. This will, in most cases, improve database performance.

Comment: adding ` has_one :status` will not limit user to having only one status, it will just load the first from database, means he can create as many statuses as he want but will be displayed only one. this should be checked at controller level as well to be sure this user don't have another status already.

Comment: it will keep the status in the db but will delete the user_id from the last one and so on.. ending in having a bunch of orphaned statuses in db.

Comment: No, he will have to abuse the ActiveRecord API deliberately to create multiple statuses. `mark.build_status` and `mark.status = Status.new` will both trigger destruction of any existing status associated with `mark`.

Comment: it will not delete the object,but you are right, it destroys the association with user just by removing the user_id from status when he creates a new one and the old status remains in db. Just tried it in console. Beside this, using a `has_one` relation is a way much better solution.

Comment: `SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."id" = ?  [["id", 7]]`

Comment: Looks like deletion to me.

Comment: sure it does, that's weird, in my case I have a bunch of records with user_id set to nil.. what rails version you used? I checked this on rails 4.

Comment: from rails 3.2 api " If set to :nullify, the associated object’s foreign key is set to NULL", http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one  could be that in rails 4 has_one is set to nullify to default and for rails 3.2 it calls destroy on related object. I can't find rails 4 api for has_one.

Comment: I have to correct myself. I was using a sample application I had and just tested a model that I knew had the `has_one` relation, but I forgot a detail. I added `dependent: :destroy` to the association. You are right, without `dependent: :destroy` associated objects will be orphaned and must be removed manually.

Answer (score 0):

in `user.rb` I admit you have `has_many : statuses`
and in `status.rb`, `belongs_to :user`

```
<ul>
  <% Person.all.each do |person| %>
    <li>
      <%= person.name %>
      <% if person.statuses.size >= 1 %>
        <em>Only one status is allowed</em>
      <% end %>
    </li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

but if you want a `person` to have only one `status`, why don't you check this when a `status` is created? or better, when he is trying to access the new action for status check if he has a status and redirect him back with a message saying "You have a status,you can have only one."

After this you can easy use:

```
user has_one :status
```

statuses_controller check:

```
def new
  if current_user.status.present?
    redirect to :back, error: "Only one status for user"
  else
    @status = current_user.status.new
  end
end
```

and when doing `Person.all.each do |person|` you can call directly `person.status` and it will be first and only one in db without needing to use an if statement. But this depends on how your app should work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stas.  status.size will not know what "status" is referring to.  It seems like you are trying to refer to the status of each individual person, so you would need something like "person.status.size >= 1".

However, looking at your Person Class, it looks like you might not have the relationship set up yet.  You need to include code in your Person class specifying that a Person has_many :statuses.  So first do this and make sure that User.first.statuses works, then add the similar code to your views.